# Filtering DataGridView via multiple combo boxes

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview

I am currently working on a Windows form app project to import excel file data into a Data Grid and apply filters based on combo boxes. I am done with the import of the data. I believe the next part should be applying the filtering code in the button for filtering and it is where I am currently stuck. Thanks in advance.

[My windows form App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH8By.png)

Snippet of my code for importing and displaying the data.

```
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + tb_path.Text + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;\" ; ";
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + dropdown_sheet.SelectedValue + "]", con);
            sda.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
            }

            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows) 
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                comboBox2.Items.Add(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                comboBox3.Items.Add(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                comboBox4.Items.Add(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                comboBox5.Items.Add(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                comboBox6.Items.Add(row.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
                comboBox7.Items.Add(row.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
                comboBox8.Items.Add(row.Cells[7].Value.ToString());
                comboBox9.Items.Add(row.Cells[8].Value.ToString());
                comboBox10.Items.Add(row.Cells[9].Value.ToString());
                comboBox11.Items.Add(row.Cells[10].Value.ToString());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
            openfile.Filter = "Excel Files | *.xlsx; *.xls; * .xlsm";

            if (openfile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.tb_path.Text = openfile.FileName;
            }

            string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + tb_path.Text + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;\" ; ";
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            con.Open();

            dropdown_sheet.DataSource = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            dropdown_sheet.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
            dropdown_sheet.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "...I am stuck..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: sorry, regarding the stuck i meant that I don't know how to continue with the code. The code runs fine importing the excel file works and I can see the data in the dataGridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find a very nice way to implement filtering UI on a datagridview by reading the following article.

It is a really nice place to start learning something and it could be adapted for other type of filtering UI (like a textbox for a search criteria instead of combobox).

[MSDN - Building a Drop-Down Filter List for a DataGridView Column Header Cell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480727.aspx)

Comment: thanks, very useful article was able to found  and do the solution by using dv.RowFilter. I am now learning how to make the program avoid null values.